# Integral Of $\oint_{|z-1|=2} \frac{\cos \pi z}{(z^2-z)\cdot (z+2i)}dz$

Tags: integration

I want to integrate the following :
$$\oint_{|z-1|=2} \frac{\cos \pi z}{(z^2-z)\cdot (z+2i)}dz$$
What I did:

1. $$\oint_{|z-1|=2} \frac{\cos \pi z}{z+2i}\cdot \left [ \frac{1}{z(z-1)}\right]dz$$
2. $$\left [ \frac{1}{z(z-1)}\right ] \rightarrow \frac{A}{z}+\frac{B}{z-1},A=-1,B=1$$
3. $$\oint_{|z-1|=2} \frac{\cos \pi z}{z+2i}\cdot \left [ \frac{-1}{z}+\frac{1}{z-1}\right]dz$$

In this step I need to evaluate so:
$$\dots=-2\pi i\cdot f(0)+2\pi i \cdot f(1) = -2\pi i\cdot\frac{1}{2i}+2\pi i\cdot\frac{cos \pi}{1+2i}=?$$
Now what? I need to present it as Complex? this is the final answer? Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Residue theorem? Or you cant multiply or add complex numbers?

Comment: I dont know if its enough, this is the final answer? I need to present it as Complex no?

Comment: What do you mean "now what"? If your calculations are correct (I didn't check), then $\;\cos\pi=-1\;$ so substitute there and that,s the value...what else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ready-made for the residue theorem.  The poles of the integrand are at $z=0$, $z=1$, and $z=-2 i$.  Which ones satsify $|z-1|\le 2$?  For each of those poles, compute the residue, which here is straightforward as the poles are simple.  Recall that, for a simple pole at $z=z_k$,

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=z_k} f(z) = \lim_{z\to z_k} (z-z_k) f(z)$$

I get for the answer

$$-\frac{\pi}{5} (9+2 i)$$

Answer (score 1):

You may use the Cauchy's integral formula, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula.
$$
\oint_{|z-1|=2} \frac{\cos \pi z}{(z^2-z)\cdot (z+2i)}dz=I_1+I_2,
$$
where
$$
I_1=\oint_{|z-1|=2} \frac{\frac{\cos \pi z}{(z+2i)z}}{z-1}dz=2\pi i\frac{\cos\pi}{1+2i},
$$
and
$$
I_2=\oint_{|z-1|=2} \frac{\frac{\cos \pi z}{(z+2i)(z-1)}}{z}dz=2\pi i\frac{\cos0}{-2i.}
$$
$I_1+I_2=-\frac{\pi}{5} (9+2 i)$.

Answer (score 0):

As you prove, the answer of integral obtain with substuting $\cos\pi$ with -1 and so it's $\displaystyle\pi\frac{-9-2i}{5}$ and "Never Mind" that your answer is a complex number.